# Tabbed content using jQuery: Show all tabs at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to arrange content into several tabs. Currently it works great for its intended purpose to show a specific `<div>` when a tab is clicked. How would I be able to create a button that could toggle "Show all tab content"? Let's say the button would look like this: `<div class="toggle"></div>`

Current code:

```
/* jQuery */

    $('#hb_container div').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');
        $('#hb_container div').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    });

/* Tabs */

    <div id="hb_container">
        <div class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1"><div class="tab-link-inner">Job<br>Info</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2"><div class="tab-link-inner">Asb.<br>By</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3"><div class="tab-link-inner">Apl.<br>No.</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4"><div class="tab-link-inner">Struc.<br>Eng.</div></div>
    </div>

/* Tabbed content */

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 24px">
    <div class="tab-content-title">Attachment Upload</div>
    <div class="single_col_container">
        <div id="frm_field_[id]_container" class="frm_form_field form-field [required_class][error_class]">
    [input]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

/* CSS */

#hb_container {
    margin: 8px 0 8px 8px;
    width: 984px;
    height: 54px;
}
    .tab-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .tab-content.current {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .tab-link {
        background: #222;
        color: #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        line-height: 14px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        width: 54px !important;
        height: 54px;
    }

        .tab-link:hover {
            background: #181818;
            color: #ffcc00;
        }

        .tab-link-inner {
            margin-top: 11px;
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean you are using the `jQuery-UI Tabs Widget`? Could we see that code, as well?

Comment: It's not the Tabs Widget, it's this: http://www.cssjockey.com/code-snippets/an-easy-way-to-create-tabbed-content-with-jquery-css

Comment: Ok, could we please see the styling for your tabs?

Comment: Edited CSS into the OP.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm fiddling now.

Comment: Can you show an example of some of the tab content?

Comment: Edited /* Tabbed content */ into the OP.

Comment: Sorry about that, edited the wrong content into it. Fixing now.

Comment: What do you mean by show all tabs? If you can see all tab content, it's not a tab anymore, isn't it?

Comment: I mean show all tabbed content together in one space, in case someone wants to see everything at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/4tfV6/2/)

**HTML**

```
    <div id="hb_container">
        <div class="tab-link current active" data-tab="tab-1"><div class="tab-link-inner">Job<br>Info</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2"><div class="tab-link-inner">Asb.<br>By</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3"><div class="tab-link-inner">Apl.<br>No.</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4"><div class="tab-link-inner">Struc.<br>Eng.</div></div>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Toggle All Tabs" class="toggle_tabs" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#hb_container div.tab-link').click(function () {
    var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');
    $('#hb_container div').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current').addClass('active');
});
$('.toggle_tabs').click(function () {
    $('.tab-content').each(function () {
        if ( ($(this).hasClass('current')) && ( $(this).hasClass('active') === false) ) {
            $(this).removeClass('current');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, fantastic work. Sorry my response was delayed, had to drop the wife off at work. Thank you again Dev!

Comment: Actually, I found one issue with it. The currently open tab does not show up when the "toggle" button is clicked; all other tabs are present though.

Comment: All the tabs show now but ONLY if one of the tabs is clicked after the page loads. If I load the page, the default "current" tab (tab-1) is visible like normal, but tab-1 won't be visible when the .toggle_tabs button is clicked.

Comment: Add the `active` class to `tab-1` in the HTML.

Comment: It's still happening after adding the active class.

Comment: I have given you the bulk. I'm sure you can work out the minor hiccups with a little toying around.

Answer (score 0):

We put the selected tab in localStorage, then did this in our tabs constructor:

```
create: function( event, ui ) {
    // manage the use of "Display All" selection
    if (activeTab == "view_all") { // find value of activeTab before doing .tabs()
        // set all panels visible
        $('.ui-tabs-panel').show();
        // clear currently active tab's status
        ui.tab.removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
        // set state of "view all" tab control (list element) to selected
        $("#tabs ul>li").last().addClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
    }
    else {
        // un-select the 'view all' element
        $("#tabs ul>li").last().removeClass('ui-tabs-active ui-state-active');
    };
},
```

Then in the activate method:

```
activate: function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.newTab[0].hasAttribute("data-id") &&
        ui.newTab[0].getAttributeNode('data-id').value == "view_all") {
        // this is the "View All" tab, so show all panel sections
        $('.ui-tabs-panel').show();
        window.localStorage.setItem("#tabs-panel", "view_all");
    }
    else if (window.localStorage) {
        if (ui.newPanel) {
            // store panel by ID (or value of your choice)
            window.localStorage.setItem("#tabs-panel", ui.newPanel.attr('id'));
            // hide all panels except selected one (new for View All functionality)
            $(".ui-tabs-panel[id!='"+ui.newPanel.attr('id')+"']").hide();
        }
        else if (window.localStorage.getItem("#tabs-panel") == "view_all") {
            $('.ui-tabs-panel').show();
        }
    }
}
```