# "Current" tab in tabbed content will not show when "all tabs" are toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/ERfWP/)

I'm trying to create a jQuery script that allows for two events to occur:

1. Create tabbed content, where only the first tab's content (`.current`) is shown when the page is loaded
2. Create a "show all tabbed content" button (`.toggle_tabs`) that toggle's the visibility of all tabbed content

The code is successfully tabbing the content of each tab; the issue is this:

- If I load the page, and then click `.toggle_tabs`, the tab that has class `.current` when the page first loads is the only tab whose content is not visible
- If I load the page, click ANY of the tabs once, and then click `.toggle_tabs`, all tabbed content will be visible.

How do I get all tabbed content to be visible when clicking `.toggle_tabs` WITHOUT having to first click one of the tabs?

Current code:

```
/* jQuery */

$('#hb_container div.tab-link').click(function () {
    var tab_id = $(this).data('tab');
    $('#hb_container div').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current').addClass('active');
});
$('.toggle_tabs').click(function () {
    $('.tab-content').each(function () {
        if ( ($(this).hasClass('current')) && ( $(this).hasClass('active') === false) ) {
            $(this).removeClass('current');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        }
    });
});

/* Tabs */

    <div id="hb_container">
        <div class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1"><div class="tab-link-inner">Job<br>Info</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2"><div class="tab-link-inner">Asb.<br>By</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3"><div class="tab-link-inner">Apl.<br>No.</div></div>
        <div class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4"><div class="tab-link-inner">Struc.<br>Eng.</div></div>
    </div>

/* Tabbed content */

<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current" style="margin-top: 24px">
    <div class="tab-content-title">Attachment Upload</div>
    <div class="single_col_container">
        <div id="frm_field_[id]_container" class="frm_form_field form-field [required_class][error_class]">
    [input]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tab-2" class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 24px">
    <div class="tab-content-title">Job Info</div>
    <div class="single_col_container">
        <div id="frm_field_[id]_container" class="frm_form_field form-field [required_class][error_class]">
    [input]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



/* CSS */

#hb_container {
    margin: 8px 0 8px 8px;
    width: 984px;
    height: 54px;
}
    .tab-content {
        display: none;
    }

    .tab-content.current {
        display: inherit;
    }

    .tab-link {
        background: #222;
        color: #ddd;
        cursor: pointer;
        float: left;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        line-height: 14px;
        margin: 0 8px 0 0;
        width: 54px !important;
        height: 54px;
    }

        .tab-link:hover {
            background: #181818;
            color: #ffcc00;
        }

        .tab-link-inner {
            margin-top: 11px;
        }
```

Comment: Is your problem similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595731/tabbed-content-using-jquery-show-all-tabs-at-once/17596513#17596513

Comment: Yes, I didn't want to bother you with fixing the remaining issue. I figured the current issue was different from what was in the OP and needed another topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest storing a status that determines whether the tabs are all being toggled or not as `toggling` here is doing:

```
// The tabs are not toggling by default
var toggling = false;
$('#toggle_tabs').click(function () {
    if (toggling) {
        // If they are being toggled, remove the current class for all tabs except the one that is active
        $('.tab-content').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this).removeClass('current');
            }
        });

        toggling = false;
    } else {
        // If they aren't being toggled, add the current class for all tabs
        $('.tab-content').each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('current');
        });

        toggling = true;
    }
});
```

And in the HTML, add the `active` class to your first tab.

```
<div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current active" style="margin-top: 24px">
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ERfWP/7/)

Comment: @EricMatthewTurano That's strange, have you seen the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERfWP/7/)? It doesn't seem to be happening to me, or maybe there's something I'm not understanding here.

Comment: Hi Camp, I deleted my comment because it applied to Brandon's response, not yours. My mistake. The issue I found with yours is this: The first time "Toggle All" is clicked, it works perfectly and all tabbed content is shown. But if after the first click of "Toggle All" you click an individual tab, and then try to click "Toggle All" a second time, it takes two clicks of "Toggle All" for all tabs to show again. Is it possible to make "Toggle All" work after one click no matter how many times it has been clicked prior?

Comment: Yes, I corrected it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ERfWP/9/. I had forgot to add a `toggling = false;` at the end of the `tab-link` click function. When you click in an individual tab, the status should be updated of course, to _not toggling_, that was the error.

Comment: I think it's perfect now, thank you so much Camp! I'll award the bounty in 20 hours when it's available.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the toggle button would show all content without affecting the "selected" state of the individual tabs. I'd recommend wrapping your tabs in a container and toggling a class on that element instead of messing with the classes on individual tabs:

```
<div id="hb_wrapper">
  <div id="tab-1">
     ...
  </div>
  ...
  <div id="tab-N">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Clicking the toggle link would toggle a `show-all` class:

```
$('#toggle_tabs').click(function () {
  $('#hb_wrapper').toggleClass('show-all');
});
```

And in the CSS, you would override the `display` property for `show-all`:

```
.show-all .tab-content {
  display: inherit;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERfWP/5/)